# Using different layout for makeindex name

Tags: header-footer, indexing, fancyhdr

I would like to use different layout for `\indexname`

```
\documentclass[8pt,b5paper,twocolumn]{extbook} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, headsep=0.4cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[icelandic, czech, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand\entry[3][]{\hangpara{2em}{1}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{{#2}}}}\ 
#3\ifx\relax#1\relax\markboth{#2}{#2}\else\markboth{#1}{#1}\fi
\par}\nopagebreak[4]
\fancypagestyle{indexstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\indexname}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\thepage}}
 }
\fancypagestyle{dictstyle}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\leftmark}}}}}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Seznam autorů fotografií}
}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{dictstyle}
\entry[headword]{headword}{translation}
\entry[headword]{headword}{translation}
\thispagestyle{indexstyle}
\clearpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

How can I change the layout of `\indexname` (in this example 'Seznam autorů fotografií') value (see picture bellow)

[image: Indexname]

and place it under the header rule the same way as are placed the first and the last headword (see picture bellow)

[image: Headwords in head]

and place it under the head rule?

Comment: It would be helpful if you detailed (preferrably via an image) exactly what the desired output that you want.

Comment: I have added illustrations and tried to clarify the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after moving `\indexname` down, you can try:

```
\smash{\raisebox{-2.5em}{\indexname}}
```

This will push `\indexname` down `2.5em` (below the header rule) and remove any vertical height/depth distortion via `\smash`.

Here's a scaled-down version of the MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt,b5paper,twocolumn]{extbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\theindex}% <cmd>
  {\thispagestyle{plain}}% <search>
  {\pagestyle{indexstyle}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\usepackage[top=2cm, headsep=0.4cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{makeidx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx
\fancypagestyle{indexstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% 0.4pt header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\smash{\raisebox{-2.5em}{\indexname}}}% Index name below header rule
  \fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\thepage}}% Page in footer, centred
 }
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}%

\makeindex
\begin{document}

\index{abcdefgh} \index{ijklmnop} \index{qrstuvwx} \index{yzabcdef}
\index{ghijklmn} \index{opqrstuv} \index{wxyzabcd} \index{efghijkl}
\index{mnopqrst} \index{uvwxyzab} \index{cdefghij} \index{klmnopqr}
\index{stuvwxyz}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The addition of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) is to "fix" the `theindex` environment. It creates the entire Index, and doesn't allow one to modify the first page style or very much else. `etoolbox` is used to patch the environment and fix the page style to `indexstyle` for the first and following pages.

Comment: I would like to place 'Index' under the headerrule. Using this `\fancypagestyle{indexstyle}` applies not to the page where the index begins but only to the remaining pages.

Comment: @chejnik: So do you want the same page style for the first page of the Index than for the rest of the Index? That is, a header rule with a "lowered" `Index`. Since you're using a `book`-related class, the Index is set as a starred chapter with page style `plain`. This can be fixed; I'm just inquiring.

Comment: Exactly. I want to keep the header rule on all pages, and place there information like Index, Chapter names, and first and last headword on the page when the main dictionary part begins. Thank you :)

Comment: @chejnik: I've updated my answer with an `etoolbox` patch of the `theindex` environment.